# Counting the number of elements that don't change in a list, in F#

Tags: f#

I have a simple list:

```
let l = [ 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 1; 1; 1 ]
```

I want to know how many elements match the first one, without a break (4 in the example)

```
let mutable i = 0
while l.[i] = l.[0] do
    i <- i + 1
```

But is there a more F# idiomatic way to do this? through one of the list functions?

Comment: Just note that `l.[i]` is O(n) on `List` in F#. So the algorithm can degrade into O(n*m) depending on the input. For array `a.[i]` is O(1) as you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```ml
let l = [ 1; 1; 1; 1; 2; 1; 1; 1 ]
let res = 
    l
    |> Seq.takeWhile(fun i -> i = l.Head)
    |> Seq.length
```

Comment: I think your approach is fine too. After all, F# is not a strictly functional language. I've just shown the idiomatic way. Also, I'm not ready to tell now how performance is different for those 2 approaches.

Comment: To handle the `[]` case, borrow that part from the other [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60439742/2807130). The only enumerator involved is the one of the tail; e.g. `function [] -> 0 | x::xs -> 1 + Seq.length (Seq.takeWhile ((=) x) xs)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to "do it yourself" in the functional paradigm, using a tail-recursive helper function:

```ml
let countInitialRun lst =
    // count how many times value appears at the start of lst
    let rec helper value lst counter =
        match lst with
        | head :: tail when head = value -> helper value tail (counter + 1)
        | _ -> counter
    // call the helper function
    // initial counter is 1 because the head is already counted
    match lst with
    | [] -> 0
    | head :: tail -> helper head tail 1
```

Comment: interesting; on large lists it's probably a lot faster than rebuilding sequences